# Как вернуть указатель на определенную часть строки в С++?

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

Пишут что можно, как и примера вовсе нет

Comment: Указатель на часть какой строки? `char*`? Или `string`?

Comment: char.  Допустим мне в строке char нужно найти какие то фрагменты и вернуть указатели на эти фрагменты в строке

Comment: @Alex у вас тоже нет примера, в какой строке искать, что найти итд. Делается примерно так: char *str = "hello world"; char *temp = str; while(*temp++){ if(*temp == 'w') break;} cout << temp;

Answer (score 4):

```
char str[] = "Hello, Dolly!";
char * с = str + 7;
cout << c;
```

Получаем

```
Dolly!
```

Примерно так. Или с помощью какой-нибудь функции.

```
const char * c = strstr("This is miss Dolly","is");
cout << c;
```

Получаем

```
is is miss Dolly
```

Но если нужен именно фрагмент (чтоб завершался нулевым символом) - то его нужно или копировать, или портить исходную строку, записывая в нужном месте нулевой символ.

Answer (score -1):

Я не очень силен в С++, но в С указатель на часть строки можно вернуть как число:

```
char* x = "I am good at math";    // строка
char* partPtr;                      // будущий указатель

for(int i = 0; x[i]!=0; i++)      
   if(x[i]=='g')                  
      partPtr = x+i;              // это указатель на строку, "good at math"
```

по идее если запихнуть его в printf("%s", partptr); то на выходе будет good at math.

Comment: [Не компилируется](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qYu-q2) ни в С, ни в С++. Зачем вы используете `unsigned int`? Взяли бы `const char *partPtr;`, и все работало бы нормально. Еще, в отличие от С, в С++ (11 и новее, вроде) нужно писать `const char *x = "...";`, потому что строковые литералы в неконстантные указатели не преобразуются.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat у меня все скомпилилось, сам проверил, но в принципе да, нагляднее сохранять в качестве указателя на символ

Comment: Компиляторы со стандартными настройками часто собирают то, что стандартом не разрешено. (Например если убрать флаг `-pedantic-errors` из примера по ссылке, оно скомпилируется. Но это все равно неправильный код. Советую выяснить, как более строгие ошибки включаются у вас в компиляторе.) *"нагляднее сохранять в качестве указателя"* Не просто нагляднее. Если размер инта вдруг окажется меньше размера указателя (как на почти любой 64-битной платформе), что несколько старших байт указателя потеряются. Если уж использовать целые (непонятно зачем), то `uintptr_t`. (Минус не мой.)